# css to get <details> <summary> to unfold if content is a :target

Tags: html, css

I have a `details` summary HTML. I want a folded section to unfold if is selected from a table of contents. How do I do this in css?

```css
details:target {
    border: double green;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #f77;
    /*:todo: also unfold*/
}
```

```html
<h1>TOC</h1>
<li><a href="#1">section 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#2">section 2</a></li>

<details id="1">
  <summary> <h1>a folding section</h1></summary>
  <p> normally hidden, but show if selected in TOC, or summary clicked on.</p>
</details>
<details id="2">
  <summary> <h1>another folding section</h1></summary>
  <p>…</p>
</details>
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, it is not possible to do with pure CSS as the element itself is not designed this way. It only handles the click. However, you can use JS and other elements to achieve what you are after.

With JS:

`window.location.hash` is how you can for example check if the window has a reference. Then look for the element with that id in the DOM and click it.

**It would probably be better to have a data attribute or something that points to the corresponding ID of the detail element**

Here is a very naive and super simple example don't take it too literally (for production use a better approach e.g. data-attributes):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  const linksWithRef = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]');
  for (const linkWithRef of linksWithRef) {
    linkWithRef.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      const ref = e.target.href.slice(e.target.href.lastIndexOf('#') + 1);
      const detailEl = document.getElementById(ref);
      detailEl.open = true;
    });
  }
});
```

```css
details:target {
  border: double green;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #f77;
}
```

```html
<h1>TOC</h1>
<li><a href="#1">section 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#2">section 2</a></li>

<details id="1">
  <summary>
    <h1>a folding section</h1>
  </summary>
  <p> normally hidden, but show if selected in TOC, or summary clicked on.</p>
</details>
<details id="2">
  <summary>
    <h1>another folding section</h1>
  </summary>
  <p>…</p>
</details>
```